# In maven - how to rename the output .war file based on the name of the profile in use

Tags: maven, war

I have three profiles in my pom.xml for our application...

1. dev (for use on a developer's)
2. qa (for use on our internal qa server)
3. prod (production).

When we run our maven build all three profiles ouput a war file with the same name. I would like to output `$profilename-somearbitraryname.war`

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend using spring profiles (`org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`) for variables that change for the application depending on the environment. That way you can build once and redeploy it again in the next environment. This might not be relevant to your case though..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You've answered yourself correctly:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <rp.build.warname>dev</rp.build.warname>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <rp.build.warname>qa</rp.build.warname>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <rp.build.warname>prod</rp.build.warname>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

but there is a simpler way to redefine WAR name:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${rp.build.warname}-somearbitraryname</finalName>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

No `maven-war-plugin` is needed.

Comment: Nice tip, but par Maven docs, profiles should not be used to produce a different output. Otherwise, as I've seen, compilations become needlessly complex.

Answer (score 26):

The answer was simple...

Define a property in each profile like this...

```xml
<profile>
    <id>qa</id>
    <properties>
        <rp.build.warname>ourapp-qa</rp.build.warname>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Then add this to your plugins...

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
        <warName>${rp.build.warname}</warName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Note: This configuration is no longer available in maven-war-plugin 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you must use `<bundleFileName>` in the `<module>`

You should follow this link to ensure your modules are rewritted: 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html

```
 <build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                 [...]
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
                            <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>anotherName-1.2.3.jar</bundleFileName>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```