# Create multiple war files and rename them with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

For the first part : I want to generate multiple war files when I build a maven project.
The second part : I want to rename those files dynamically.

For example : the file that is generated now is called test.war . If I want to generate this file multiple times on a single build I would want the files to be name like this : test_1.war, test_2.war , test_3.war...

Do you guys have any Idea how can this be achieved ? I can also create a .bat file that would do those things but I am not quite sure how :)

Thank you

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882322/how-do-i-get-maven-2-to-build-2-separate-war-files)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that does not apply to my case.  I have only one project, with one web.xml and I want to use this file for all the files that are generated. Basically what I want to do is a loop of the part that is generating the war file creating more than one file.

Comment: I strongly suggest to build a multi module maven project, where each war is the output of a single module. that's an answer to generate multiple war files. For the renaming i think create profiles is the best solution you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129581/in-maven-how-to-rename-the-output-war-file-based-on-the-name-of-the-profile-i) hope that will help

Comment: Thank you, indeed it would be much better solution to have a multi module project, but that would mean in my situation I would have duplicated code. I was thinking maybe I could do a .bat file with a for loop in which i could have something like "mvn clean install", but here comes the renaming problem because every time when I create the file it will have the same name

Comment: I don't know if it exist a solution with  .bat file but you can keep your post until someone else could find an appropriate solution. Good Luck

Comment: The basic question here is: Why do you need multiple war files? should they contain different files? or what?

Comment: Hello, the war files would have to contain the same files but with different configurations. For example for the test_1.war file I would have testClass.java with a variable var = test_1, and for test_2.war I would have testClass.java with the variable var = test_2. But this I would have to configure in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for all your answers. I managed to create those files using a .bat file that looks like this :

> `call mvn -DfinalName=test_1 package`
>     `call mvn -DfinalName=test_2 package`
>   `call mvn -DfinalName=test_3 package`
>   `call mvn -DfinalName=test_4 package`

and in the pom.xml I added a property `<finalName>` :

> `<properties>
>       <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
>   </properties>`

and in the build section I added this :

> `<build>
>         <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
>
>   ...
>    </build>`

.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure whether this works but possibly you could try something like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test_1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            <goals>
            <configuration>
                <warName>test_1.war</warName>
            </configuration>
        </execution> 
        <execution>
            <id>test_2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            <goals>
            <configuration>
                <warName>test_2.war</warName>
            </configuration>
        </execution> 
    <executions>
  </plugin>
```