# Maven: don't know the position for the <FinalName> tag

Tags: java, maven, rename, war

I have a long pom file with multiple plugins and specifications.
I read in other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129581/in-maven-how-to-rename-the-output-war-file-based-on-the-name-of-the-profile-i) that I should add the line `<finalName>desiderTitle.war</finalName>` under the  section, but I also have more than one of these and can't understand or guess in which one and why I should add it. It should become something like this:

```
 <build>
   <finalName>WhatEverYouLikey</finalName>
 </build>
```

I tried to search for tutorials on this, with no success.

Comment: There is only one build section. Can you post your current POM?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also have more than one of these..."? Each pom.xml should have only the one `<build>...</build>` element.

Comment: Sadly I cannot post it, because it's an university project I'm working on and I'm not sure I can share it (even if it's just the pom file).
However I've just noticed that the build tags are each under a profile tag. Does it help?

Let's say I have just a single build tag OR I understand which of these build tag is the correct one. Do I have to add the <finalName> tag in a specific order/position, wrapped inside it with some kind of correlation to the other tags?

Comment: Tags in pom.xml files are (in general) not ordered. Therefore `<finalName>...</finalName>` can be anywhere within the `<build>...</build>`, so long as the build tag is it's immediate container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are confused about the profiles in your `POM`. Take a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to understand the concept.

Basically, profiles are a way to build the project in different ways. So multiple `<build>` tags can be present under each profile, and different `finalName`s can be specified.

You can select the profile  using the `-P <profileName>` option when you build the project.